# Redirect included files

Tags: php

I have this file which stores my db info

```
<?php
$DBServer = 'this';
$DBUser   = 'is';
$DBPass   = 'my';
$DBName   = 'secret';
?>
```

And it is included where I need it to connect to the db. My question is, how can I prevent users from going to `mywebsite/db_info.php` ? I know it displays a blank to them and they don't have access to the info, but I'd like to redirect them to the index page. The problem comes when this file being included in another one, it will always redirect to the index page when used(when I will connect to the db).

Comment: [This](http://serverfault.com/a/175625) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With apache, You can put your file in a separate folder within a .htaccess file with this content:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

So you will have:

```
/yourPrivateFolder/.htacces
/yourPrivateFolder/db_info.php
```

This will prevent external access to your file

Comment: Will the .htaccess rules apply for everything in its folder?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc yes it will

Answer (score 1):

First, what is the point to redirect a file with important information like database access? No users should have access to this file, or even his name and path.

There are some approaches you can choose, one security option it is to allocate your db_info.php file outside the public root of your domain. Exemple:

yourdomain.com = **/home/user/www/**

your file should be: **/home/user/db_info.php** (or outsite /www/ folder!)

Comment: How do I include it in php if it's outside the www folder?

Comment: You need to include the canonicalized absolute pathname of file. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] gives you the path of your public folder, you should let your file below it.